# how to make a pivot table based on the occurrence of a value in a certain parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

hello!

For example, I have a table with mailing addresses. Some mailing addresses read my emails and some didn't.

The table looks like this:
[image]

I want to make a pit, in which the index will be an email, in the columns number of the letter (1,2,3,4). And in the values, the fact that the user read or not read (read / not read).

Tell me, how can I make a table like this in pandas?

[image]

just pivot
table = pd.pivot_table(opens_with_names, columns=['email_no'],  values = 'Email Address')

Answer (score 0):

`df`

```
    adress  number
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   A   4
3   B   1
4   B   2
```

use `crosstab` and `reindex`

```
(pd.crosstab(df.adress, df.number)
 .reindex(columns=range(1, df.number.max() + 1))
 .fillna(0)
 .replace({1:'yes', 0:'no'})
)
```

`output`

```
number  1   2   3   4
adress              
A   yes yes no  yes
B   yes yes no  no
```